# Синхронизаниция по Integer в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Есть следующая учебная программка.

В программе есть синхронизированный блок. Синхронизация работает если использовать в качестве объекта синхронизации что угодно и даже массив `values`, но не работает при использовании `Integer` `count`.

```
synchronized (count) {
    incrementCount();
    values[getCount()]++;
}
```

В тоже время если объявить другой объект `Integer`, то синхронизация по нему будет работать.

```
synchronized (other) {
    incrementCount();
    values[getCount()]++;
}
```

Почему нельзя использовать синхронизацию по `count`?

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Counter counter1 = new Counter();
        Counter counter2 = new Counter();
        Counter counter3 = new Counter();
        Counter counter4 = new Counter();

        counter1.start();
        counter2.start();
        counter3.start();
        counter4.start();

        counter1.join();
        counter2.join();
        counter3.join();
        counter4.join();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            if (values[i] != 1) {
                System.out.println("Массив values содержит элементы неравные 1");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static Integer count = 0;
    public static int[] values = new int[105];

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 105; i++) {
            values[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void incrementCount() {
        count++;
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public static class Counter extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            do {
                synchronized (count) {
                    incrementCount();
                    values[getCount()]++;

                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            } while (getCount() < 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Синхронизация по инту? Вам знаком товарищ Даг Ли? Он пишет пакет для многопоточности в джаве. Обратите внимание на AtomicInteger, полагаю, что он решит Ваши проблемы

Comment: Нет. Синхронизация по обьекту Integer, в данном случае по count из стороки public static Integer count = 0; этот способ не работает. Синхронизация по values или другому Integer не задействованному в синхронизированном блоке работает

Comment: В вашем примере нет синхронизации по `Integer`.

Comment: нет, потому что она  не работает, но я предельно ясно описал ситуацию. Но если не понятно я исправил код и теперь она там есть..

Answer (score 2):

Объекты типа `Integer` иммутабельны, операция инкремента `count++` не меняет состояние объекта по ссылке,  после инкремента переменная `count` будет ссылаться на другой объект в куче.

```
Integer count = 0; 
...
synchronized (count) {
     incrementCount(); // тут происходит count++;
     ...
}
```

Что тут происходит:

1. Вы захватываете монитор (`MonitorEnter`) на объекте, доступном по ссылке `count`.
2. Вы инкрементируете значение `count`, теперь `count` ссылается на новый `Integer`.
3. В секцию `synchronized` может зайти другой поток, т.к. по ссылке `count` объект, на котором еще не произошел `MonitorEnter`.

Как-то так.

Comment: Stranger in the Q тут написано что каменты с стиле "спасибо" не приняты, только по делу. Ваш ответ понятен и исчерпывающий, плюсануть я пока не могу. Так что спасибо!

Comment: @Fayras извините, просто вы добавили комментарий в свой вопрос и я расценил его как непонимание моего ответа, извините еще раз

Comment: Stranger in the Q правильно написал - причем еще добавлю что иногда у вас работает синхронизация а иногда нет. Например первый поток захватил монитор, второй увидел что count захвачен и ждет. Первый меняет count, третий переходит по count и видит уже совсем другой объект по ссылке и так как он не захвачен, никого не ждет. Делайте вот так:    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " +count);  сразу после вхождения в монитор. Будет явно видно на чем потоки синхронизировались.

Comment: Обратите внимание что когда поток собирается захватить монитор, но еще не захватил, он ищет объект захвата "под гонкой" (так как count - это указатель на объект, а не сам объект).

Comment: @dSH я хотел сюда картинку из книги с поездами добавить, но не стал, не будем усложнять и так непростую для новичков тему